# How to change Border color of ComboBox using code?

Tags: wpf, combobox, border

I have a ComboBox and I want to change the border's color to red to mark it as a mandatory field. I am generating this ComboBox column dynamically through my Code. What are the properties that I should set in order to change the border color?

```
  DataGridTemplateColumn dataGridComboBoxTemplateColumnObj = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
  dataGridComboBoxTemplateColumnObj.Header = column.Header;
  FrameworkElementFactory comboBoxFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ComboBox));
  Binding bindingItemSourceObj = new Binding(column.ItemsSourcePropertyName);
  comboBoxFactory.SetValue(ComboBox.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Stretch);
  comboBoxFactory.SetValue(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, bindingItemSourceObj);              
  comboBoxFactory.SetValue(ComboBox.SelectedValuePathProperty, column.ValuePropertyName);

  Binding selectedValueBindingObj = new Binding(column.PropertyName);
  selectedValueBindingObj.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
  selectedValueBindingObj.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
  comboBoxFactory.SetValue(ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty, selectedValueBindingObj);
  dataGridComboBoxTemplateColumnObj.CellTemplate = new DataTemplate();
  dataGridComboBoxTemplateColumnObj.CellTemplate.VisualTree = comboBoxFactory;
  dataGridColumnObj = dataGridComboBoxTemplateColumnObj;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox"/>
```

You can just set the value of `Border.BorderBrushProperty`:

```
MyComboBox.SetValue(Border.BorderBrushProperty, Brushes.Red);
```

In this way you change exactly the border color of the `ComboBox` to red.

**Edit**:
I added this example for your specific `FrameworkElementFactory`:

```
FrameworkElementFactory comboBoxFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ComboBox));
comboBoxFactory.SetValue(Border.BorderBrushProperty, Brushes.Red);

ControlTemplate ct = new ControlTemplate(typeof(ComboBox));
ct.VisualTree = comboBoxFactory;
MyComboBox.Template = ct;
```

Comment: it says Brushes.Red is not a proper value for BorderBrush Property

Comment: @PhOeNiX _it_? I tested with a simple WPF project in C#, output: change exactlty the border color of `MyComboBox` to red, so _it_ works.

Comment: der is no combobox in xaml...'comboBoxFactory' is the name of the frameworkelement representing the combobox

Comment: @PhOeNiX You're wrong, look at the [relative page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox) on MSDN Library.

Comment: @ gliderkite... u got it wrong, m saying that der is no combobox in xaml in my project. I am generating it through code as it is dynamic generation during runtime.

Comment: @PhOeNiX And what's the difference? If you have a [ComboBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox) in XAML or not you can anyway set its `BorderBrushProperty` as I wrote.